# HP ILO smart error after replacing

Tags: hp, ilo

I’ve just replaced a SAS drive that was reporting a smart error and had orange led indicating problem.

New drive is in and no more orange light, green light flashing as normal but ILO still reporting smart error. Should it still say this until it restores the new drive? From memory I thought it would remove the error immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the replacement was faulty.